# Can't Install VLC Media Player (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, vlc

I have a problem while trying to install VLC Media Player.

I type sudo apt-get install vlc in the Terminal, and this is what I get:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
[sudo] password for hagaymosko: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be     installed
Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be     installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What does that mean, and how do I fix it?