# VLC fails to install on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, vlc

I'm (desperately) trying to install VLC on my 14.04.

```
apt-cache policy vlc
```

returns:

```
vlc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
     2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     2.1.2-2build2 0
        500 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

When I try to install, then I get the infamous `vlc-nox` issue:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Attempt to install `vlc-nox` leads to request of installation of `libfreerdp1`, and then to this message:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreerdp1

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  freerdp-x11
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-client1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1
  libfreerdp-common1.1.0 libfreerdp-core1.1 libfreerdp-crypto1.1
  libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-locale1.1 libfreerdp-plugins-standard
  libfreerdp-primitives1.1 libfreerdp-rail1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1
  libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1 libwinpr-environment0.1 libwinpr-file0.1
  libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1 libwinpr-input0.1
  libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1 libwinpr-path0.1
  libwinpr-pool0.1 libwinpr-registry0.1 libwinpr-rpc0.1 libwinpr-sspi0.1
  libwinpr-synch0.1 libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1 libwinpr-utils0.1
  libxfreerdp-client1.1 remmina-plugin-rdp
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libfreerdp1
```

Now, I don't understand why vlc installation would lead to removing these packages? Is there any way around this issue?

Already went through (reasonable) solutions suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210596/vlc-depends-on-vlc-nox), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497511/cant-install-vlc-media-player-ubuntu-14-04), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566161/vlc-media-player-not-installing-in-ubuntu-14-04), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508153/vlc-installation-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/342888/how-can-i-solve-vlcs-dependency-vlc-nox) apart from adding repositories.

---

Output of `apt-cache policy libfreerdp-cache1.1`:

```
libfreerdp-cache1.1:
  Installed: 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-2ubuntu1~trusty1
  Candidate: 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-2ubuntu1~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-2ubuntu1~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-master/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output of `apt-cache policy remmina-plugin-rdp`:

```
remmina-plugin-rdp:
  Installed: 1.1.1-ppa1+484+201508180831~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 1.1.1-ppa1+484+201508180831~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.1-ppa1+484+201508180831~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-master/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.0-4ubuntu3 0
        500 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libfreerdp-cache1.1`

Comment: And please the output of `apt-cache policy remmina-plugin-rdp`

Comment: @A.B. Added requested info.

Comment: Don't hate me for this comment, but did you try installing via Software Center?? http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html

Comment: @JoaquínO No hate on SE, it's all love here ;) Thanks for comment - I did indeed tried it.

Comment: I would install from source.  Don’t even mess around, repos are usually an older version.

Comment: what is output of `apt-cache policy vlc-nox`

Comment: Yeah, vlc-nox doesn't need any rdp dependencies although vlc does.

Answer (score 5):

The first part of your problem is that you have disabled unstable PPAs or repos. [Please take a look at this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) for additional information. This would be the first step in solving your issue.

After you cleared up that, please enter the following into a Terminal window.

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc-nox
 sudo apt-get autoclean
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
 sudo apt-get -f install
 sudo apt-get autoremove
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Another recommendation would be using the official VLC repo than the Ubuntu one. These are kept up to date and are a lot more efficient in my opinion. If you want to do that, please enter the following below:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Thanks @Nickolaus L. Unfortunately, that didn't help. `vlc-nox` still complains.

Comment: what is output of `apt-cache policy vlc-nox`

Comment: The Videolan ppa's are a joke. The Master ppa is dead & worthless, the Stable one puts up builds that aren't upgrades to existing Ubuntu repo ones.

Comment: This doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple. you are using a ppa that has numerous freerdp packages but not libfreerdp1.

https://launchpad.net/~remmina-ppa-team/+archive/ubuntu/remmina-master

So when trying to install vlc it depends on libfreerdp1 which is available in the ubuntu repos. However libfreerdp1 from ubuntu conflicts with some of your installed freerdp packages, they have to be removed to install vlc & libfreerdp1.

To resolve or proceed, several choices,

1. use ppa-purge on the ppa, then install vlc.
2. install vlc, lose all those packages (seems useless then to have ppa so 1 is better
3. contact the ppa maintainers & report the problem, maybe they will  explain why no libfreerdp1 & provide a vlc build that uses new packages/soname.
4. See if you can rebuild vlc so libfreerdp1 isn't needed, ck. what vivid does where libfreerdp1 is gone.
5. Don't install vlc, leave things as is.

Comment: That indeed might do the job, but won't it mean I'll have to downgrade to older version of remmina?

Comment: I gave you 5 choices,  they encompass All of your available options. I'd contact the ppa maintainers, do as you please...

Answer (score -2):

I recommend using aptitude on the command line to resolve dependency issues and broken packages, then revisit the answer given by Nickolaus L.